# How do you explicitly instantiate variadic template functions? C++

Tags: c++

h file:

Example Function:

```
template<typename... Args>
std::string print(const char *format, Args... args);
```

Attempts:

```
extern template std::string print(const char *, const char *);
extern template std::string print(const char *, const char *, int);
```

cpp file:

```
template<typename... Args>
string print(const char *format, Args... args) {
    return string;
}
```

I get

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Comment: Please provide [mcve] in addition to copy-pasted (not paraphrased) error messages.

Comment: Why `extern`? that's seems like a typo, that says it's declared somewhere else.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_instantiation

Comment: You instantiate a declaration. Where is the **definition** instantiated?

Comment: @StoryTeller Indeed, wrong term, I wanted to say defined.

Comment: in a cpp file, the declaration/instantiations are in a h file and are not members of a class

Comment: Remove the extern, that's enough to make it a definition, as you need.

Comment: if i remove extern, i get an error that i explicitly instantiate but no definition is available

Comment: So that means that you don't have the proper elements in your cpp file. But we don't know what is missing because the code is not complete ([mcve]).

Comment: All I have in a cpp file is:

Comment: template<typename... Args>
string print(const char *format, Args... args) {
    return string;
}

Comment: Everything else is in .h file (function declaration and instantiations i provided above)

Comment: Don't add information into the comment section. [edit] it into your qeustion

Answer (score 1):

Instantiating declarations is all well and good, but the definitions need to be instantiated as well. Add these to your cpp file:

```
template<typename... Args>
string print(const char *format, Args... args) {
    return string;
}

template std::string print(const char *, const char *);
template std::string print(const char *, const char *, int);
```

Now those functions will be defined as well. Linkage should find them if your do the linking properly.

Comment: Thank you! It actually seems that declarations do not need to be instantiated at all?

Comment: @IamEncrypted - Strictly speaking no they don't need to be. But it serves a documentation purpose.

Comment: I think this is a bad answer